# Having trouble with ChunkInputStream reading a chunk id tag

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have been working on a audio/video container (like AVI) for use with Java and I have run into a error when reading a chunk id tag from the file. Following is the error that I have encountered;

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 10
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at com.hachisoftware.ism.ChunkInputStream.readChunk(ChunkInputStream.java:27)
at Main.run(Main.java:72)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

The error is happing in this bit of code, on the `String id = in.readUTF();` line;

```
public Chunk readChunk(Chunk type) throws IOException {

    String id = in.readUTF();

    if(!type.chuckID.equalsIgnoreCase(id.toString()))
        throw new IOException("Can't cast Chunk '" + type.chuckID + "' to '" + id + "'");

    type.readChunk(in);

    return type;
}
```

All the source code can be found at: [GitHub](https://github.com/William2405/ISM-API/tree/master/src)

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets here.

Comment: How did you write this data? readUTF() can only read data that was written with writeUTF().

Comment: I'm using this to write a chunk; 
`public void write(Chunk obj) throws IOException {
  out.writeUTF(obj.chuckID);
  flush();
  obj.writeChunk(out);
  flush();
 }`

Comment: And what does writeChunk() do?